# window.getComputedStyle always returns measurement in pixels

Tags: javascript, object, methods, window

I am just wondering why, for instance, `window.getComputedStyle(element).top` always returns the measurement in pixels, even in cases whereby the `top` position is set explicitly to `%` like so `element.style.top = 25 + '%'`.

I have not been able to find any information online. **Anybody know why this is the case?!**

Comment: because relative input values have to be calculated to pixels for monitor display. If you want `%` you need to calculate it based on parent container dimensions

Comment: @charlietfl that makes sense. thanks!

Comment: Similar with the variety of color formats...they get converted and you get back `rgb` even when you input hex or other format values

Comment: @charlietfl yeah, i noticed that one ages ago. that one always caused me issues lol

Comment: It does not always return pixels. For example, `window.getComputedStyle(element).gap` returns a `%` value if defined as such. (at least it does in firefox)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is **`element.style.top`**.

---

That is the intended behaviour of `window.getComputedStyle`.

"The `window.getComputedStyle()` method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain."

Meaning that everything that is a unit other than pixels will be calculated or processed and then presented as pixels. Even the name GetComputedStyle hints that.

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) if you want.

Comment: Not entirely true: if you provide ```border-radius``` in percents, then ```window.getComputedStyle()``` will return it also in percents, not in pixels.

Comment: Do you really need per cent values for border-radius?